# Central differencing in time?

Tags: finite-difference-methods

I am taking a numerical analysis course and we are discussing solving the advection equation using finite differencing.

My professor said that central differencing in time might not work for the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ term but didn't go into detail as to why.

I did some Googling but could find any examples of central differencing in time.

Is there a theoretical reason that central differencing time cannot work?

Comment: Are you sure he mentioned central difference in *time*, not *space* ? It is well known that the central difference leads to huge oscillations in numerical approximations of the advection equation when applied to the spatial derivative.